# how to get the database values by using hibernate and how to display that values in a primefaces dataTable?

Tags: primefaces

Here i have some doubts.If you know the answer please post here.

How to get the list of values into database table by using hibernate?

How to display that values into primefaces dataTable?

Here i am posting what i am trying .see below

```
    <p:dataTable id="users" value="#{user.listUsers}" var="user"
        sortBy="user.id" rows="10" style="width: 30%">

        <p:column>

            <f:facet name="header">

                <h:outputText value="ID" />

            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" />

        </p:column>

        <p:column>

            <f:facet name="header">

                <h:outputText value="Name" />

            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />

        </p:column>

        <p:column>

            <f:facet name="header">

                <h:outputText value="Surname" />

            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{user.surName}" />

        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Refer this before posting a question : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Here i am finding the answer how to display a table values into primefaces dataTable.

Here i am placing what i am trying code.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{actions.messages}" var="act">
                        <p:column style="width:10%;text-align:left" filterBy="#{act.id}" >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="ID" id="id" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{act.id}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:20%;text-align:left"
                            sortBy="#{act.action}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Customer" id="customer" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{act.action}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:40%;text-align:left"
                            sortBy="#{act.scheduled}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Date" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{act.scheduled}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:30%;text-align:left"
                            sortBy="#{act.status}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Action" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{act.status}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bean class i am developing name called Actions.

@ManagedBean(name = "actions", eager = true)

@SessionScoped

public class Actions implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;

private String action;

private String assignedTo;

private String assignedBy;

private Date scheduled;

private Date actual;

private String outcome;

private String status;
```

//write here setter & getter methods of the above properties

```
public ArrayList<Actions> getMessages() {
    ActionsDao dao = new ActionsDao();
    return dao.getActions();

}
```

}

you can use the annotations or hbm file that yours choice to map the bean class.

Here i am using only mapping file why because, first i am trying to create annotations but it raised some problems that jar files are some problem.your using the correct jar files that not a problem you can continue the annotations otherwise hbm file is best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hibernate dao class name called ActionsDao

```
public class ActionsDao {
public Session session;

public ArrayList<Actions> getActions() {

    session = Util.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Actions> actionsList = (ArrayList<Actions>) session
                .createQuery("from Actions").list();

        tx.commit();
        boolean found = false;

        for (Actions actions : actionsList) {

            Actions action = new Actions();
            action.setId(actions.getId());
            action.setAction(actions.getAction());
            action.setActual(actions.getActual());
            action.setAssignedBy(actions.getAssignedBy());
            action.setAssignedTo(actions.getAssignedTo());
            action.setScheduled(actions.getScheduled());
            action.setOutcome(actions.getOutcome());
            action.setStatus(actions.getStatus());

            actionsList.contains(action);

            found = true;

        }
        if (found) {
            return actionsList;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error In getActions() -->" + e.getMessage());
        return (null);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

}